# Pass stdin to plistbuddy

Tags: bash, plistbuddy

I have a script to show the content of the Info.plist of .ipa files:

```
myTmpDir=`mktemp -d 2>/dev/null || mktemp -d -t 'myTmpDir'`
unzip -q "$1" -d "${myTmpDir}";
pathToFile=${myTmpDir}/Payload/*.app/Info.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print" ${pathToFile}
```

With large files this can take some time until they are extracted to the temp folder just to read a small Info.plist (xml) file.
I wondered if I can just extract Info.plist file and pass that to plistbuddy? I've tried:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print" /dev/stdin <<< \
$(unzip -qp test.ipa Payload/*.app/Info.plist)
```

but this yields

```
Unexpected character b at line 1
Error Reading File: /dev/stdin
```

The extraction is working fine. When running `unzip -qp test.ipa Payload/*.app/Info.plist` I get the output of the Info.plist file to the terminal:

```
$ unzip -qp test.ipa Payload/*.app/Info.plist
bplist00?&


!"#$%&'()*+5:;*<=>?ABCDECFGHIJKXYjmwxyIN}~N_BuildMachineOSBuild_CFBundleDevelopm...
```

How can I pass the content of the Info.plist to plistbuddy?

Comment: You might want to use `plutil` instead, which can read from standard input using `-` as the file name.

Comment: I recently had to stop using `plutil` and use `PlistBuddy` instead in order to change `com.apple.developer.team-identifier` which `plutil` insisted I was providing an incorrect value for. Otherwise, I have preferred `plutil` in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with plutil as chepner suggested:

```
unzip -qp test.ipa Payload/*.app/Info.plist | plutil  -convert xml1 -r -o - -- -
```

Comment: It really works like a magic. Could you explain meaning of these hyphens?

Comment: The flags are all described in the plutil manpage. Type "man plutil" to read it. "-convert" converts the plist to the requested format. "xml1" means the text-based xml format as opposed to the binary format. "-r" changes the whitespace of json output; json output hasn't been requested here so this arg does nothing. "-o" specifies the output filename; the following "-" means stdout. "--" means all subsequent args are filenames even if they begin with a dash. The final argument, then, is the input filename, "-", meaning stdin.

Answer (score 2):

Usually commands support "-" as a synonym of stdin, but this PlistBuddy tool doesn't.

But you can still extract just one file from your ipa, save it as a temporary file, and then run PlistBuddy on that file:

```
tempPlist="$(mktemp)"
unzip -qp test.ipa "Payload/*.app/Info.plist" > "$tempPlist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print "$tempPlist"
rm "$tempPlist"
```